# double quotes in zsh parameter expansion

Tags: zsh, double-quotes, parameter-expansion

I have two test cases in `zsh`

1. A. without quotes

   ```
   ~$ y=(${(f)$(echo -e "a b\nc d")}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b c d>
   ```
2. B. with quotes

   ```
   ~$ y=(${(f)"$(echo -e "a b\nc d")"}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b>
   <c d>
   ```

However if I first assign the output of `echo` to a variable, the quotes do not have any effect:

1. C. without quotes

   ```
   ~$ x=$(echo -e "a b\nc d"); y=(${(f)${x}}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b>
   <c d>
   ```
2. D. with quotes

   ```
   ~$ x=$(echo -e "a b\nc d"); y=(${(f)"${x}"}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b>
   <c d>
   ```

Questions:

1. comparing A and B, what causes the differences?
2. comparing A and C, what causes the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiment, I feel the following rules may have been applied

#### Sec1. direct use

1. A. without quotes

   ```
   ~$ y=(${(f)$(echo -e "a b\nc d")}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b c d>
   ```

   **unquoted `$()` produces words split by `IFS`**: see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution
2. B. with quotes

   ```
   ~$ y=(${(f)"$(echo -e "a b\nc d")"}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b>
   <c d>
   ```

   **quoted `$()` produces a single string**

### Sec2. assignment to scalar

1. C. without quotes

   ```
   ~$ x=$(echo -e "a b\nc d"); y=(${(f)${x}}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b>
   <c d>
   ```

   **when being assigned to a scalar, it works as automatically quoted**
2. D. with quotes

   ```
   ~$ x=$(echo -e "a b\nc d"); y=(${(f)"${x}"}); printf "<%s>\n" "${y[@]}"
   <a b>
   <c d>
   ```

   **when being assigned to a scalar, it works as automatically quoted**

#### Sec3. assignment to array

`y=($(echo -e "a b\nc d"))`

Follows **Sec1** http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution